# Component inside JMenuBar wants to align far right after JSeparator?

Tags: java, swing, jmenu, jmenubar, jseparator

Take a look at this image:

[image]

As you can see, I have a JSeparator between my "Auto Refreshing" JCheckBox and my "Show Column" menu, and my "Show Column" menu is wanting to be as far right as possible. Why is it not aligning itself to the left, like everything else before the JSeparator? And I can't seem to make it do so, here is my current code:

```
JCheckBox pulling = new JCheckBox("Auto Refreshing");
...
menuBar.add(pulling);

menuBar.add(new javax.swing.JSeparator(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL));

JMenu showMenu = new JMenu("Show Column");
showMenu.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
menuBar.add(showMenu);
```

Comment: JMenuBar is only designed to work with JMenu children; adding something other than a JMenu is asking for trouble.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. You have been asked for a SSCCE before. Until the problem is solved you don't know what part of your code is the problem. We don't have time to continually ask for more information, so all the relevant information should be posted with the question so we don't have to guess about anything.

Comment: @camickr. I'm sorry, but I did provide a SSCCE. What else would you care to see? Nothing else relates to the problem. After this menuBar is set as the JFrame's JMenuBar via setJMenuBar(...)

Comment: @danglingPointer, That is not a SSCCE. The code can't be compiled and executed. Read the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the size of the JSeparator, it wanted to take up as much horizontal space as possible. So, my solution was to restrict it's size so that it could only be one pixel wide max:

```
JSeparator menuSep = new JSeparator(javax.swing.SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
menuSep.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(1, 1000));
menuBar.add(menuSep);
```

Comment: If a proper SSCCE was posted you could have had the answer 2 days ago.

Answer (score 2):

This [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#alignment) might be helpful. A quote:

> By default, most components have center X and Y alignment. However, buttons, combo boxes, labels, and menu items have a different default X alignment value: LEFT_ALIGNMENT.

So you can see that placement logic differs, in other words, don't count on it. However, I do not know why your manual alignment to left did not work. Most likely the problem is the size of your last menu. What you can do, is use [glue as filler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html#filler) since `JMenuBar` has a `BoxLayout`.

```
menuBar.add(showMenu);
menuBar.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
```

This invisible space will be added to the end of your menu and it will push components before it the left.

Comment: So adding the horizontal glue moved the menu over slightly such that it was pretty much centered. However you suggestion did help me find a solution, so thanks!